# How to set up TestNG+Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, testng, jenkins-plugins

I'm using Jenkins to run some testNG test, when the build is finished i get the following message at the end:

```
[INFO] Build failures were ignored.
TestNG Reports Processing: START
Looking for TestNG results report in workspace using pattern: **/test-output/testng-result.xml
Did not find any matching files.
Finished: SUCCESS
```

I looked at the workspace in Jenkins and there is no folder named test-output, the question here is, how do I tell jenkins to create the folder with the results in there?

Here is my pom.xml if needed:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.barco.automation</groupId>
    <artifactId>barcoAutomation</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>barcoAutomation</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
        <!-- added -->
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.8</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.uncommons</groupId>
            <artifactId>reportng</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.42.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>My Automated tests</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.16</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you need to add post-build action in jenkins to add relative path of the testng-result.xml which can be found in your workspace.

Comment: I have the following action: **Publish TestNG Results->TestNG XML report pattern**, with this in it: _**/test-output/testng-result.xml_

Comment: so did you resolve? If not find the testng-result.xml in your workspace and add the missing relative path infront of /test-output/testng-result.xml

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you to use [HTML Report Publisher Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HTML+Publisher+Plugin) in Jenkins addon and configure your reports as below. This will allow you to view the report for every build. Through this you will be able to archive all your testNG reports build wise and it can be seen on the Job level as well. Once you are installing this plugin, configure your job and add a POST-BUILD-STEP (to enable the HTML REPORT PUBLISHER) and follow the location setting for testNG reports. Please refer to the screenshot below and let me know in case of any questions. Hope this helps!

Typically, your TestNG reports generated here :

```
<Jenkins-Location>\jobs\<JOB_NAME>\workspace\target\html
```

[image]